# How do I iterate a dynamic table in webpage using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, ui-automation

How do I iterate a dynamic table in webpage using python selenium? When I iterating the loop it's only clicking on the first row and extracting the data every time. Not click to second row?

Comment: what you tried?post the code,post the error you are facing

Comment: share the relevant HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example below. You can run this code to view the result.

```
from selenium import webdriver


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp')

rows_in_table = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="customers"]//tr[th or td]')
for element in rows_in_table:
    print(element.text.replace('\n', ''))
browser.quit()
```

Hope, this will help you.